Reapplying data validation rules after script changes their display
I have an Apps Scripts which I implemented in order to split a phrase across different cells to help automate filling in a google sheets. There are data validation rules implemented on this sheeet which I need to keep for QA purposes. As part of my code in order for it to run i have to clear and re-apply the data validation rules in order for it to work. However, when I reapply the data validation drop down visually looks different and I dont understand why.
function final_split(e) {
// Open the spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Get the specific sheet by name
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Campaigns'); 
  
  // Get the range in column DR from row 3 onwards
  var startRow = 3;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('DR' + startRow + ':DR' + sheet.getLastRow());
  
  // Get the values from column DR starting from row 3
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  // Iterate over each row in the range
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Get the phrase in the current cell
    var phrase = data[i][0];
    
    // Check if the cell is not empty
    if (phrase) {
      // Split the phrase by underscore and skip the first element
      var parts = phrase.split('_').slice(1);
      
      // Set the values in the respective row from column F onwards
      for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
        var cell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6 + j); // Column F is column index 6
            
            // Save the current data validation rule
            var validationRule = cell.getDataValidation();
            
            // Clear data validation temporarily
            if (validationRule) {
              cell.clearDataValidations();
            }
            
            // Set the value
            cell.setValue(parts[j]);
            
            // Restore data validation
            if (validationRule) {
              cell.setDataValidation(validationRule);

              
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  


This question is similar to: Set Data Validation Display style in Apps Script. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
